# DB migration error- Unable to migrate db in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 as development db. I used this code to migrate db

```
rake db:migrate
```

Also tried this `rails db:migrate` 
However I got this error

```
*SyntaxError: /Users/kangkanlahkar/Desktop/Codes/Ruby/practice/db/migrate/20170721152949_create_users.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting &. or :: or '[' or '.'
/Users/kangkanlahkar/Desktop/Codes/Ruby/practice/db/migrate/20170721152949_create_users.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting &. or :: or '[' or '.'*
```

Any idea how to fix it. I am using mac.

But the command `rails db:migrate:status` works fine

Content of *20170721152949_create_users.rb* file

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string, :name
      t.string, :email
      t.integer :phone
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: the problem from this migration file db\migrate\20170721152949_create_users.rb, can you upload the content

Comment: I have added the content of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove extra *commas* after `t.string` that's causing the syntax error. Try the following:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.integer :phone
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting &. or :: or '[' or '.'

You have to remove the *commas(,)* after `t.string`

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.integer :phone
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the commas after `t.string`:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.integer :phone
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```